# Antonym of 'calculated, deduced (value)'

Tags: word-request

In computer programming, I'm looking for a word to describe values that are not calculated or deduced based on other values. The only word came to mind is 'authentic' but it seems far-fetching. What are my options?

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers and comments but 'constant' is not what I am trying to express. I want to say this value is not a 'calculated column' (database metaphor) or a transformation of another pre-existing value, instead, the value carries unique information that if you delete this value, some information is lost whereas if you delete a calculated value, nothing is lost as long as you have the formula.

Maybe 'raw' is the best fit here?

Comment: Such a value sounds like a *constant*, I think.

Comment: Constant sounds like what you're looking for. I never thought I'd say this here but would you like to put up some sample code to make sure?

Comment: Raw data or input data perhaps.

Comment: Ah, you might say it is a fundamental value and not a derived value.

Comment: @SamuelLijin I think 'independent' is closer to what I want to express, which can be agnostic to mutability.

Comment: @NS.X. now that your context is more specific, I'm loath to suggest "independent", as it's not exactly the best fit for your situation. I don't know what you mean by "agnostic to", but the concept of mutability is quite different from what you're discussing here. Given what you've described, I would go with *raw data*.

Comment: Where do the numbers come from? I'm inclined to say something like, "These numbers derive from real world measurements, and the computer cannot re-create them if they are deleted. But I don't know whether the numbers come from real world measurements, so that part may have to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess would be an **independent variable** or an **unattached variable**.

Note that these are **NOT** technical computer programming terms.

Answer (score 1):

Some words have very specific meanings within computer programming. Below are some standard(-ish) definitions. **constant** and **static** are keywords in many languages, with precise meanings. I would steer clear from using them unless they fit your needs exactly. **persistent** and **fixed** are not common keywords, and are open to interpretation depending on use.

A **Constant** is a variable that will never change.

A **Static** variable is one whose value does not differ between instances of a class.

**Persistent** means that it exists both before and after some event that would otherwise reset the value, like a page load, or a restart.

**Fixed** means 'unchanging'.

Answer (score 1):

original value is usually uncalculated, unbiased and untransformed, which gives the sense of rawness.

Answer (score 0):

I would use **fixed values**.
*Variables* are usually dependent on other values or calculations, while *fixed* values are not.

> X=5
>   (X is fixed)
>
> Y=a(determined elsewhere)+4
>   (Y is variable)